# CSS: Repeating linear gradients for Internet Explorer supported?

Tags: css

I know that IE 6-9 (and 10...) support linear gradients, but my question is does it support **repeating** linear gradients like for Firefox? Firefox example:

```
    -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(left, #c5ccd4, #c5ccd4 0.31098em, #cbd2d8 0.31536em,  
    #cbd2d8 0.438em);
```

For the following IE linear gradient equivalent, what can I add to make it repeat if that is possible? IE:

```
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#c5ccd4',     
    endColorstr='#cbd2d8',GradientType=0 );
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You might want to be careful with implementing repeating linear gradients as they have some issues in various browsers. See Eric Meyer's write up on this:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/tests/gradient-repeat.html